# Where can I send my 0.005% 1 PPM tempco calibration resistors to find out their "true" value?

Tags: resistors, calibration

edit: putting this at the top because people keep answering questions I didn't ask:

***Where can I get this done cheaply by a place that is hobbyist friendly? I don't even know where to look.***

I imagine there are plenty of labs that do this kind of thing, but any that I can find via google do not disclose pricing and seem geared exclusively towards volume / B2B and are not hobbyist friendly.

Are there any cheap-ish labs that are friendly to the hobbyist where I could send my precision resistors to find out their true value down to the PPM range or better?  PPB would be ideal.  I'm using these to calibrate my 5.5 and 6.5 digit multimeters.

Bonus question: I'm interested in getting a calibration report on my precision 5v reference and a few capacitors / inductors as well so a place that can do all of that on the cheap would be ideal.

edit: additional notes based on clarifying questions people have asked:

1. I don't have a specific need aside from just being able to calibrate my bench multimeters up to 6.5 digits
2. It was recommended that I send a multimeter in for calibration instead of the resistors and use it as a transfer standard. Fair enough, but whether resistors or a meter, this is the heart of the question: where can I get this done cheaply by a place that is hobbyist friendly? I don't even know where to look.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing as a hobbyist that you need to nail down the resistor value to better than 0.005%? Is there some way you can choose one resistor to be your "reference standard" and measure all the other ones relative to it?

Comment: To be fair, I don't actually need this level of precision for anything specific.  I've purchased some high end surplus bench multimeters on eBay for my home lab and I'd just like to be able to calibrate them to their full resolution.  I've already spent a couple hundred at digikey on 0.1 through 1 gig ohm resistors at the highest precision / lowest PPM TempCo they carry.  If another hundred or so can get me down to the PPM level it'd be very satisfying.  

TLDR: passion

Comment: To me, the easiest thing to do would be to send the 6-1/2 digit multimeter to a cal service. Then you can use it to calibrate or at least check your 5-1/2 digit multimeter, your 5 V reference supply and all the resistors. I have no idea the cost, but I'd think it shouldn't be more than 10% of the cost of a new instrument.  Since an Agilent 34401A lists for $1000 this puts you pretty close to your $100 target. Best place to go probably depends what's local to you.

Comment: Perfection is an illusion; an expensive one. The accuracy of any measuring device does not improve, beyond a certain point, with increasingly perfect calibration. You may have a near perfect standard resistor but the ohmmeter is limited by its inherent resolution. From the Zen of Python: "practicality beats purity".

Comment: Places that service and sell used lab eqt. usually have the necessary eqt. to do this if they calibrate eqt too.  Especially ones dealing with SA's (Spectrum Analyzers) the classical mixer type (high BW).  You can also look for NIST certified labs labs, they are usually associated.

Comment: This really gets to the heart of the question, but how can I find these places? All my surplus purchases are via eBay.

Comment: The Photon: Can you recommend such a service?

Comment: @Nick, if you can, go somewhere local --- if you have to ship your instrument two ways it's going to add significantly to your costs.

Answer (score 4):

### Calibrate the *instrument*

Modern DMM's use internal tables of data to implement multi-point calibration. You will not be able to do this yourself without a service manual and their test/calibration software suite.

Manual calibration with resistors will allow you create your own calibration function, but then you will have to manually apply it to each measurement (or suck the measurements through a data drain and do it there).

Factory calibration is not expensive and you don't need to be a huge enterprise to access it.

There are also 3rd party calibration services and labs. Most test equipment rental companies also have attached labs.

Here is an example of US pricing for reference. It is about 10% of original purchase price.

[image]

Comment: That list is pretty much what I'm looking for. How/where did you find it? How can I find a similar list for my own multimeters? How can I get a report on an individual component instead of a meter?

Comment: @Nick: What manufacturer makes your multimeters?

Comment: I have a HP/Agilent 3478A and a Fluke 8840A plus a few others of lesser quality/spec.  The Fluke appears spot-on already, I just can't verify it.  The HP was way out (several percent) on resistance so I tend to trust it less but DC readings match the Fluke perfectly.  Not sure which one would be better to have professionally calibrated.

Comment: @DrFried, From the new/demo/refurb column I'm thinking this is pricing for calibration as an add-on if you are buying (or maybe renting?) an instrument from a dealer that carries both new and used stuff? Even so it's probably a reasonable ball-park number for calibration service.

Comment: And if I could figure out where it came from it might actually be useful to me...

Comment: @Nick -- http://MetricTest.com

Comment: @ThePhoton -- True. IIRC, it's the same pricing if you send them your unit as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered that the intersection between "hobbyist" and "ready to pay for better than 1% precision" is a pretty darn small market? In fact, most "pro" places I know don't need 6.5 digits calibrated!

My guess is that what you're asking for doesn't exist. Instead, I suggest you contact two or three of the labs that you do find, and ask them what it would cost to calibrate whatever it is you want to have calibrated. And when I say "contact," I may very well mean "call them on the phone." Yes, it may be expensive, but then again, it's unlikely that what you want to have done could be done very much cheaper than the cheapest bidder out of three separate labs would provide.

Also: There used to be a reason people use real places to buy equipment, instead of eBay. eBay may be cheaper, but as soon as you get into this kind of question, those savings are eaten up. Unfortunately, most people don't realize that there is actual value in having people to talk to until it's too late, which means that many of the knowledgeable physical places that might have existed, have gone out of business, and what remains is either fairly expensive, or very far away. Also, some of those places would drive themselves out of business, as they would either not actually talk to you, or it was just sales guys on commission wanting to do upsells, or they would staff the talking with the cheapest idiots they could find, so it's not /all/ eBays and China-direct's fault...

Comment: Btw: This is the fourth hit from searching for "8840A calibration" on Google: http://www.teknetelectronics.com/Search.asp?p_ID=109&pDo=DETAIL  $91 for "standard" calibration; $195 for ISO accredited with certificate.